# Set work percentage for each employee

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following situation. I have some employees with job percentage for each. Every time a job comes I need to allocate it to a certain employee according to job percentage for example:

```
Employee 1  Job Percentage
James       75%
Adam        15%
Cindy       10%
```

So when a job comes available it must be allocated to James 75% of the time, Adam 15% and Cindy 10%. These are stored in a MySQL database.

If there were only 2 employees, this would be easy to solve as I could get a random number from 1 to 100 (rand 1,100) and see if it's in range of one of the employees percentages and assign the job accordingly. The problem here is that the number of employees can change and employees can be added and removed. Can anyone suggest a solution for this? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Add the job to the employee with less job percentage then update it's row?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the cumulative percentage.  Then you can use `rand()`.  So:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             (@cume := @cume + percentage) as cume
      from allocations a cross join
           (select @cume := 0)
     ) a cross join
     (select rand() as r) r
where r.r between cume - percentage and cume
limit 1;
```

The idea is to get ranges such as:

```
 0%     75%
75%     90%
90%    100%
```

The purpose of putting the `rand()` in a subquery is to get only one row.  Because the query uses `between`, there *could* be a duplicate every few hundred million runs, so I added the `limit 1`.  It uses `between` just in case `rand()` returns 0 or 1.